# Show posts in category

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have a problem in the loop by the time I make a wp_query .

What I'm trying to do :

- Bring only 4 random posts of the Videos category.
- Videos This category is the Post -Format Video type (I believe that this does not influence much, because I am wanting to bring all the videos category.

But he is not showing my loop ! Could me of a Help ?

```
$query_video = new WP_Query( $args );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

if( $query_video->have_posts()) : while( $query_video->have_posts()) : $query_video->the_post();
```

Comment: Your arguments (`$args = array()`)should be before your query (`$query_video = new WP_Query( $args );`)

Comment: Didn't you just forget to declare your $args array _before_ the query, and not after ?